# Meta Regex: test if regex is only a string (no regex "wildcards")

Tags: c++, regex, boost-regex

I have a (assumed well formed) regex expresion R. I want to test if the regex expression is just a single match (all letters, numbers, and escaped expressions) or could be swapped with anything else. This function, "HasWildCards", would work like this:

```
bool a = HasWildCards("asdf");//returns false
bool b = HasWildCards("asdf*");//returns true
bool c = HasWildCards("asdf[123]");//returns true
bool d = HasWildCards("asdf\\[123\\]");//returns false
```

I am using boost::regex, if that helps at all. I was thinking of  checking if the regex expression matches something like this:

```
(^(([\[\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\{\}])))?(\\[QEdwsDWSbAZzB])?([^\\][\[\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\}])?
```

I've tested this on a few expressions (using the RegexTest tool of grepWin)

So non-escaped regex symbol to start, non-escaped flag,non-escaped regex sumbol in body. Is there an alternative? Did I screw something up? Is there a better way?

Comment: `"[^\\\\][\\.\\^\\$\\[\\]\\?\\+\\*\\{\\}]"` If a special character exists without escaping before it, you may need to extend the second character class to include other special characters I missed off the top of my head. All backslashes are doubled up for being escaped into the string.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen On a few expressions yeah, and whenever I break it I have to edit the regex...

Comment: @MadScienceDreams you might want to mention that in your question, in case someone assumes you haven't actually tested anything

Comment: @Robadob yeah, its gotta seach if its not escaped at the beginning of the line (yours requires that there be a non-escape character before the symbol) and doesn't check for the other escape symbold (\Q\E, for example)

Comment: Might this be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What do you need this for?

Comment: @m.buettner Taking in regex expressions of a tree path, as a command line argument, need to find all paths that match the regex, I want to allow the node deliminator ('/') to be regexed (so .*foo[0-1] will have any length in the tree). While I could do a brute force search of everything, it would be much faster to be able to not do any search on nodes that are "complete" (aka "/asdf/") could also split out each line as a regex. I guess I should really be checking if any of the wild cards can be replaced by the node deliminator...

Comment: @Robadob: your check fails for something like `"\\\\*"` - a backslash (escaped with another backslash) repeated zero or more times. It's not enough to check for special characters with no backslashes before them - you need to check for special characters preceded by an even number (possibly zero) of backslashes. Personally, I'd not try to express that with a regexp, but write a simple single-pass algorithm that checks for special characters while keeping track of the length of the most recent run of backslashes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik perhaps this then `"([^\\\\](\\\\\\\\)*[\\.\\^\\$\\[\\]\\?\\+\\*\\=\{\\}])"` It's not great for trying to express with Regex, but its fun to try :p

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a quick two-step way to test for this.
Instead of testing for escaped characters *and* wildcards in one regex, the first line of your function could remove escaped characters, then the second line would test the remaining string for wildcard-type expressions.

```
.*((\[.+?\])|(\{[0-9]*,[0-9]*\})|(\*)|(\+)).*
```

will match a string that contains any *, +, {#,#}, or [] expression. In your function, return whether or not the passed string matches this expression.